# Which Design pattern should i use for loop over steps

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

I am to run certain number of statements (which are executing .exe) in a loop.

```
ForEach(object obj in ListOfVersions)
{
  Step 1: call Exe1 Args=obj.somevalues
  Log Step 1 completed for obj

  Step 2: call Exe2 Args=obj.somevalues
  Log Step 2 completed for obj

  Step 3: call Exe3 Args=obj.somevalues
  Log step 3 completed for obj
}

Step 4: call Exe4
```

Is there any specific design pattern available to use for above situation.

Edit:

> Every Exe different and is performing different operation with
>   different parameters.

Comment: I voted to migrate this to http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: How do you expect the code to change? More steps? Evolution of the list to another data structure? Interdependencies?

Comment: Are all of the calls exactly the same, except for the name of the executable?

Comment: Sounds like the builder pattern to me.. The builder pattern is perfect for "steps".

Comment: @Team-Joki: i am looking for solutions like you provided.. a pattern which is good for steps and their status loging.

Comment: @Team-JoKi Builder is creational and here is obviously needed behavioural pattern.. Builder pattern is perfect to avoid multiple constructors with different signatures, especially when some variants of constructors has 2+ parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good candidate for command pattern.

Comment: you might want to add a more detailed explanation or code to show how the command pattern would help.